# What are the granthas written by Sri SomAnanda nAtha?

Tags: scripture, agamas, kashmiri-shaivism

Sri Somananda was main guru in the kashmir agamic tradition.

What are the main texts attributed to him ? And also if some minor texts or commentaries if available.

Comment: The only work of Somananda I've read is the Shivadrishti, which focuses on criticizing the Sphotavada school of Bhartrihari.  Ironically Sphotavada is one of the philosophies that agree most closely with Kashmiri Shaivism, but it has long been noted that [small differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissism_of_small_differences) can produce great conflicts.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan. He has written some commentaries too wikipedia gives two of them. Another wiki article says about the thing you mentioned about sphota. But it resembles vivarta advaita vedanta and hence.criticised. I feel it's not closer to KS.

Comment: I would say that Kashmiri Shaivism is at least closer to Bhartrihari's Sphotavada philosophy than it is to Adi Shankaracharya's Advaita Vedanta philosophy.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan i am saying that bhartrharis is related to vedanta than KS

Comment: Yeah, Bhartrihari's ideas are somewhat related to Vedanta, although it's not clear whether he was an actual member of the Vedanta school as he doesn't mention the Brahma Sutras or the methods of Mimamsa in his works.  But compared to Advaita Vedanta and other Vedantic philosophies, Sphotavada has a lot of points of agreement with Kashmiri Shaivism.